# Backwards compatible PageTransformer

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-animation, nineoldandroids

I'm trying to animate items in a ViewPager and the PageTransformer fits the bill. I want it to be backwards compatible to Android 2.2 so am using the support v4 library. However...

> As property animation is only supported as of Android 3.0 and forward, setting a PageTransformer on a > ViewPager on earlier platform versions will be ignored.

so PageTransformer won't work on older versions

I'm using [Jake Wharton's NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/) library so I could use that API, but I'm not sure how to do animation for a ViewPager.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 8):

You need to implement the `PageTransformer` using the `AnimatorProxy` wrapper to set the transformation properties on the views.

Then the tough part is that the `ViewPager` will ignore the `PageTransformer` in lower API versions.  So you need to modify the `ViewPager` itself to use the `PageTransformer`.

I have a [forked version of the support library on GitHub](http://www.github.com/kedzie/android_frameworks_support) which allows this as well as using NineOldAndroids animators for custom fragment transitions.  Use the animator-transition branch. It is a maven project so you can build it from the v4 subdirectory.

```
public class ZoomOutPageTransformer implements PageTransformer {
    private static float MIN_SCALE = 0.85f;
    private static float MIN_ALPHA = 0.5f;

    public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
        int pageWidth = view.getWidth();
        int pageHeight = view.getHeight();

        AnimatorProxy proxy = AnimatorProxy.wrap(view);

        if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
            // This page is way off-screen to the left.
            proxy.setAlpha(0);
        } else if (position <= 1) { // [-1,1]
            // Modify the default slide transition to shrink the page as well
            float scaleFactor = Math.max(MIN_SCALE, 1 - Math.abs(position));
            float vertMargin = pageHeight * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2;
            float horzMargin = pageWidth * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2;
            if (position < 0) {
                proxy.setTranslationX(horzMargin - vertMargin / 2);
            } else {
                proxy.setTranslationX(-horzMargin + vertMargin / 2);
            }

            // Scale the page down (between MIN_SCALE and 1)
            proxy.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
            proxy.setScaleY(scaleFactor);

            // Fade the page relative to its size.
            proxy.setAlpha(MIN_ALPHA +
                (scaleFactor - MIN_SCALE) /
                (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - MIN_ALPHA));
        } else { // (1,+Infinity]
            // This page is way off-screen to the right.
            proxy.setAlpha(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice! The next problem is that I actually want to animate the (position+1) page as my ViewPager shows three items and the middle item is the one which I want to be selected. I don't think I can use the PageTransformer can I?

I think I'm going to have to animate them manually in the onPageSelected method. What do you think?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean.  The transformations are always on 2 views, in your case either view 1+2 or 2+3. Only two are on screen at once. You can perform any transformation on both visible views.  Also you might wanna check out JazzyViewPager which has some built-in transitions. It also uses NineOldAndroids.  https://github.com/jfeinstein10/JazzyViewPager

Comment: @mark.kedzierski Is there any other way to get `.jar` file which is provided with the above source? If it is possible please upload the `jar` file.

Comment: I don't know how to upload a file in relation to an answer.  I'd be happy to email it to you.

Answer (score 3):

As @mark.kedzierski said copied the ViewPager class from [here](https://raw.github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java) and removed the if statement for the version (check below) and called it TransformableViewPager

```
public void setPageTransformer(boolean reverseDrawingOrder, PageTransformer transformer) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        final boolean hasTransformer = transformer != null;
        final boolean needsPopulate = hasTransformer != (mPageTransformer != null);
        mPageTransformer = transformer;
        setChildrenDrawingOrderEnabledCompat(hasTransformer);
        if (hasTransformer) {
            mDrawingOrder = reverseDrawingOrder ? DRAW_ORDER_REVERSE : DRAW_ORDER_FORWARD;
        } else {
            mDrawingOrder = DRAW_ORDER_DEFAULT;
        }
        if (needsPopulate) populate();
    }
}
```

I also had to change all PageTransformer to ViewPager.PageTransformer. Then did the transformations in a custom PageTranformer like this,

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
    // > 11 version
    view.setAlpha(0);
}
else
{
    // Nine Old Androids version
    ViewHelper.setAlpha(view, 0);
 }
```

Ithink proxy can also be used so you don't have to write the version check.This worked even for 2.2